# Adding a custom layout to Magento 1.9

Tags: templates, magento-1.9

I am trying to add a custom layout to our Magento 1 platform. I followed the instructions located on this page, https://blog.magestore.com/how-to-add-new-layout-template-for-magento/ and I was unsuccessful. I'm looking for advice and instructions on how to accomplish this task.

This is the config file I made

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DFSCopper_Page>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DFSCopper_Page>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <one_column_wo_name module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>1 column without name</label>
                    <template>page/one_column_wo_name.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>one_column_wo_name</layout_handle>
                </one_column_wo_name>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

Nothing changed when I added this file, and the new template phtml file. The second step in adding the Store_Page.xml file, that file is already present in that folder. That is the only step I was confused on.

Comment: You say nothing changed. But it is not clear what you expect to change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache after creating the new files?

Comment: how does one clear the cache?